# How can I generate FIRRTL from chisel code?

Tags: chisel

How can I generate FIRRTL file from chisel code? I have installed sbt, firrtl and verilator according to the github wiki. And created a chisel code for simple adder. I want to generate the FIRRTL and covert it to Verilog? My problem is how to get the firrtl file from the chisel code.
Thanks.

Source file : MyQueueTest/src/main/scala/example/MyQueueDriver.scala

```
package example

import chisel3._
import chisel3.util._

class MyQueue extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val a = Flipped(Decoupled(UInt(32.W)))
    val b = Flipped(Decoupled(UInt(32.W)))
    val z = Decoupled(UInt(32.W))
  })  

  val qa = Queue(io.a)
  val qb = Queue(io.b)

  qa.nodeq()
  qb.nodeq()

  when (qa.valid && qb.valid && io.z.ready) {
    io.z.enq(qa.deq() + qb.deq())
  }
}

object MyQueueDriver extends App {
  chisel3.Driver.execute(args, () => new MyQueue)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40470153/is-there-a-simple-example-of-how-to-generate-verilog-from-chisel3-module).
The solution could be to use full template provided [here](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel-template), or you can simply do that:

Add these lines at the end of your scala sources :

```
object YourModuleDriver extends App {
  chisel3.Driver.execute(args, () => new YourModule)
}
```

Replacing "YourModule" by the name of your module.

And add a build.sbt file in the same directory of your sources with these lines :

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

resolvers ++= Seq(
  Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots"),
  Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases")
)

libraryDependencies += "edu.berkeley.cs" %% "chisel3" % "3.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

To generate FIRRTL and Verilog you will just have to do :

```
$ sbt "run-main YourModuleDriver"
```

And the FIRRTL (yourmodule.fir) /Verilog (yourmodule.v) sources will be in generated directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was able to see the Verilog file.
When I have `package <some-package-name>` in my source code 
`$ sbt "run-main YourModuleDriver"` didnt work. It gave Class Not Found exception.

Comment: What is the name of your module ? Can you post sources ?

Comment: I apologize for the long delay in response. I added the source code to the question. When I removed the `package` in the source code and move the source code to dir MyQueueTest/src/main/scala/ it works like a charm.

Comment: Please, don't forget to mark question has "solved" then.