# Running specific tests and getting Verilog from a Chisel project based on the chisel-template

Tags: riscv, chisel

After a lot of poking my nose into different Chisel stuff out there, I decided it was time to try a thing of my own. Quite unexpectedly, the thing, a simple thing, but still, the thing I made based on the [chisel-template](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel-template) works successfully.

I even managed to confirm that by running the simplest of tests. It is a dummy 32-bit ALU that contains (for now) a submodule intended for bitwise operation. I wrote the test following the existing test of GCD, so my test file, `Alu32UnitTest.scala`, contains these important lines:

```
package alu32
import chisel3.iotesters
import chisel3.iotesters.{PeekPokeTester,Driver,ChiselFlatSpec}
class Alu32BoolTests(dut: Alu32) extends PeekPokeTester(dut) {
    for (i <- 0 until 9) {
        //first provide random values
        val a = rnd.nextInt(256)
        val b = rnd.nextInt(256)
        val f = rnd.nextInt(16)

        //decide what to expect based on opcode
        var output = 0
        if (f == 8) {
            output = a & b
        } else if (f == 14) {
            output = a | b
        } else if (f == 6) {
            output = a ^ b
        } else output = 0

        //connect the generated inputs to dut
        poke(dut.io.a, a)
        poke(dut.io.b, b)
        poke(dut.io.f, f)

        //clock
        step(1)

        //check if everything is where it should be
        expect(dut.io.y, output)
    }
}
}

class Alu32UnitTester extends ChiselFlatSpec {
    behavior of "Alu32"
    backends foreach {backend =>
    it should s"perform correct math operation on dynamic operand in $backend" 
    in {
      Driver(() => new Alu32, backend)((dut) => new Alu32BoolTests(dut)) should be (true)
    }
  }
}
```

I run this test using (after running `sbt`):

```
> testOnly alu32.AluUnitTester
```

and it correctly says `SUCCESS` when it's good and it complains when I change the internals of the ALU. I've come to that `testOnly` line, only by looking at the README of [chisel-template](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel-template) and pressing [Tab] after `test`, `testOnly` and so on.

The next thing I wanted to do was to get Verilog code so I tried running the commands provided at [chisel-tutorial](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel-tutorial), I mean those including `run-main`. That, of course, resulted in errors as, I realized, no such tests were defined in my `Alu32UnitTest.scala` So I tried adapting the lines found in GCD and that led me to notice another file in tests/scala - a `GCDMain.scala`. So I went ahead and adapted that into:

```
package alu32

import chisel3._

object Alu32Main extends App {
  iotesters.Driver.execute(args, () => new Alu32) {
    dut => new Alu32UnitTester(dut)
  }
}

object Alu32Repl extends App {
  iotesters.Driver.executeFirrtlRepl(args, () => new Alu32)
}
```

and called it `Alu32Main.scala`. With that one created, now nothing works :)

When I try the one that did work:

```
> testOnly alu32.AluUnitTester
```

I get now the following response:

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/apaj/ChiselProjects/alu32/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[warn] there were 8 feature warnings; re-run with -feature for details
[warn] one warning found
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/apaj/ChiselProjects/alu32/target/scala-2.11/test-classes...
[error] /home/apaj/ChiselProjects/alu32/src/test/scala/alu32/alu32Main.scala:7: too many arguments for constructor Alu32UnitTester: ()alu32.Alu32UnitTester
[error]     dut => new Alu32UnitTester(dut)
[error]            ^
[error] one error found
[error] (test:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 10 s, completed Jan 15, 2018 5:16:12 PM
```

I notice how it complains over having to many arguments. However, if the argument `dut` is removed, than it complains about mismatched types.

At one point, somehow, can't remember to reconstruct how, I did get a response similar to the one presented [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40903620/compiling-chisel-source-files-in-chisel-project-template), but I really don't remember how.

I am sure that this is a beginner's issue, overlooking something probably obvious, so I hope you'll find time and help out.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you please post the Alu32Tester code (and maybe the Alu32 code too).  I think you are right that it is something simple but I need to see a little more.

Comment: Apologies for a delayed reply, I was away. You were right in the answer, thank you very much, but let me add the requested code to the question, just for completeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you meant to refer to your PeekPokeTester implementation *class Alu32BoolTests(dut: Alu32)* and not
your scala test harness *class Alu32UnitTester*.
To be specific line 7 should be

```
dut => new Alu32BoolTests(dut)
```

and not

```
dut => new Alu32UnitTester(dut)
```

Comment: Yes, very good, thank you. Now I can run the test as follows: `test:runMain alu32.Alu32Main`

Answer (score 1):

This is just for completeness, main issue was solved by Chick Marley's answer. However, as the second part of the question was about obtaining Verilog, here is what needs to be added to the `alu32UnitTests.scala`:

```
class Alu32Tester extends ChiselFlatSpec {
  private val backendNames = if(firrtl.FileUtils.isCommandAvailable("verilator")) {
    Array("firrtl", "verilator")
  }
  else {
    Array("firrtl")
  }
  for ( backendName <- backendNames ) {
    "Alu32" should s"calculate proper greatest common denominator (with $backendName)" in {
      Driver(() => new Alu32, backendName) {
        c => new Alu32BoolTests(c)
      } should be (true)
    }
  }

  "Basic test using Driver.execute" should "be used as an alternative way to run specification" in {
    iotesters.Driver.execute(Array(), () => new Alu32) {
      c => new Alu32BoolTests(c)
    } should be (true)
  }

  "using --backend-name verilator" should "be an alternative way to run using verilator" in {
    if(backendNames.contains("verilator")) {
      iotesters.Driver.execute(Array("--backend-name", "verilator"), () => new Alu32) {
        c => new Alu32BoolTests(c)
      } should be(true)
    }
  }

  "running with --is-verbose" should "show more about what's going on in your tester" in {
    iotesters.Driver.execute(Array("--is-verbose"), () => new Alu32) {
      c => new Alu32BoolTests(c)
    } should be(true)
  }

  "running with --fint-write-vcd" should "create a vcd file from your test" in {
    iotesters.Driver.execute(Array("--fint-write-vcd"), () => new Alu32) {
      c => new Alu32BoolTests(c)
    } should be(true)
  }

  "using --help" should s"show the many options available" in {
    iotesters.Driver.execute(Array("--help"), () => new Alu32) {
      c => new Alu32BoolTests(c)
    } should be (true)
  }
}
```

Once that is saved and compiled, Verilog is obtained as follows:

```
test:runMain alu32.Alu32Main --backend-name=verilator
```