# Simplest way to generate Verilog code from Chisel code

Tags: scala, build, verilog, chisel

What is the simplest way to **generate Verilog** code from existing Chisel code?

Would i have to **create my own build file**?

For example from a **standalone scala file** (AND.scala) like the following one..

```
import Chisel._

class AND extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val a = Bool(INPUT)
    val b = Bool(INPUT)
    val out = Bool(OUTPUT)
  })
  io.out := io.a & io.b
}
```

I have the complete **Chisel3 Toolchain installed** under ubuntu 16.4.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a simple example of how to generate verilog from Chisel3 module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40470153/is-there-a-simple-example-of-how-to-generate-verilog-from-chisel3-module)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See answer here: [Is there a simple example of how to generate verilog from Chisel3 module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40470153/is-there-a-simple-example-of-how-to-generate-verilog-from-chisel3-module)

In short, create a build.sbt file at the root of your project with the following in it:

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.13"

resolvers ++= Seq(
  Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots"),
  Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases")
)

libraryDependencies += "edu.berkeley.cs" %% "chisel3" % "3.4.4"
```

Add this code to AND.scala

```
object ANDDriver extends App {
  (new chisel3.stage.ChiselStage).emitVerilog(new AND, args)
}
```

Type `sbt run` on the command line at the root of your project.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer! Guess i oversaw the other thread. I just tried it and it works. NOTE: jdk8 and sbt have to be installed for this to work! (jdk9 did not work for me)

Comment: Anyway to generate verilog to a "target folder" instead of the same place as `build.sbt`?

Comment: Yep! Chisel and FIRRTL have command-line options. Notice how we pass `args` to `chisel3.Driver.execute`? We are propagating the command-line arguments sent to `ANDDriver` to Chisel. You can pass arguments like so: `sbt "run --help"`. The specific one for "target folder" is `--target-dir` or `-td`, ie. `sbt "run -td my_target_dir`

Comment: Thanks! +1 for your answer.

Comment: chisel3.Driver is deprecated. Can you update this answer?

Comment: Done, thanks for the ping!