# How to import getVerilog() function from the bootcamp examples?

Tags: chisel

I am not sure I understand how to use the **getVerilog** function from:
https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel-bootcamp/blob/master/2.1_first_module.ipynb

```
[error] passthrough_test.scala:18:11: not found: value getVerilog
[error]   println(getVerilog(new PassThrough(10)))
[error]           ^
[error] one error found
[error] (Test / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Nov 21, 2018 1:53:02 PM
```

I did import chisel3._ but that does not seem to be enough.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `getVerilog` method is defined only in the Bootcamp. There's an equivalent method for Chisel versions prior to Chisel 3.2.0 called `Driver.emitVerilog`. For Chisel versions after 3.2.0, the correct method is `(new chisel3.stage.ChiselStage).emitVerilog`:

```scala
import chisel3._
import chisel3.stage.ChiselStage
    
class Foo extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {})
  
  printf("I'm a foo")
}

/* For Chisel versions <3.2.0 use the following: */
Driver.emitVerilog(new Foo)

/* For Chisel >=3.2.0 use the following: */
(new ChiselStage).emitVerilog(new Foo)
```

As an additional reference, the specific implementation of `getVerilog` in the Chisel Bootcamp is [here](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel-bootcamp/blob/0644990c895121a7ce32777121bd3cf6732cc9e1/source/load-ivy.sc#L6). This looks almost identical to what `Driver.emitVerilog` is doing [here](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/blob/2f40920b6d13d0ea573a3c6eebee3ffedfa83ddc/src/main/scala/chisel3/Driver.scala#L101). There was a similar, but slightly different question about generating Verilog that was [brought up in a different SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41815657/simplest-way-to-generate-verilog-code-from-chisel-code).

Usually if you're wondering if some API exists, it can be useful to search through the Chisel3 API reference. E.g., you can consult the documentation for `ChiselStage` for methods related to compiling Chisel to FIRRTL IR or Verilog: [ChiselStage API](https://www.chisel-lang.org/api/latest/chisel3/stage/ChiselStage.html).

For more control over Verilog generation, you'll want to use the `ChiselStage` class' method `execute(args: Array[String], annotations: AnnotationSeq)` if using Chisel >=3.2.0. Earlier versions of Chisel should use the `Driver` object's method `Driver.execute(args: Array[String], dut: () => RawModule)`.

Note: `ChiselStage.emitVerilog` does allow you pass command line arguments and annotations to the Chisel compiler for more control over the generated FIRRTL IR or Verilog.