# Can not do "import chisel3._"

Tags: chisel

I want to use chisel3.2, and have installed "sbt" into Mac OS-X.
I wrote my project (Scala file), and downloaded template of project.
I did;

```
sbt
```

It did a lint of "scala" but did not import chisel3 object.
Indeed this is caused by PATH setting, but there is no information about it.
Does anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: You need to add chisel3 as a libraryDependency, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40470153/is-there-a-simple-example-of-how-to-generate-verilog-from-chisel3-module/40474979#40474979

Comment: I use the chisel template, directory structure is root-of-proj->project->MySOurce.scala, and build.sbt is in root-of-proj dir.

Comment: sbt generates new dir and its file in project directory; project and target.

Comment: "sbt" command enters into command-line itself. Is this normal behavior, there is no explanation about it.

Comment: download error: Caught java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 93: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/edu/berkeley/cs/chisel-iotesters_2.11/[

Comment: I made site for How to run chisel; https://github.com/IAMAl/How2Start_Chisel3

Comment: Thanks for creating this. Your experiences here are illustrating the need for more detailed docs about the basic Scala ecosystem and SBT.

Comment: Per SBT, just typing `sbt` indeed opens an interactive shell. SBT is the standard tool in the Scala world, you can refer to its extensive documentation for more information: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/index.html

Comment: Per the download error, can you post that as a separate question with more information including your build.sbt? Thanks.