# how to set generated directory of emitVerilog?

Tags: chisel

I just started with chisel-template.

I added below statement in DecoupledGCD.scala per a [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40470153/is-there-a-simple-example-of-how-to-generate-verilog-from-chisel3-module?noredirect=1&lq=1).

```
object DecoupledGcdDriver extends App {
    (new ChiselStage)emitVerilog(new DecoupledGcd(16))
}
```

When I ran

```
sbt run
```

The verilog file was generated in current directory per se.

However either I run

```
sbt "runMain gcd.DecoupledGcdDriver --help"
```

or

```
sbt "runMain gcd.DecoupledGcdDriver --target-dir <my dir>"
```

doesn't change anything.

My build.sbt is from latest template:

```
ThisBuild / scalaVersion     := "2.12.13"
ThisBuild / version          := "0.1.0"
ThisBuild / organization     := "com.github.riggy2013"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "chisel-gcd",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "edu.berkeley.cs" %% "chisel3" % "3.4.3",
      "edu.berkeley.cs" %% "chiseltest" % "0.3.3" % "test"
```

I don't have enough "reputation" so start a new thread here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending [App](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.13/scala/App.html) is just syntactic sugar for writing a `main` function with the argument `args: Array[String]`. If you want the arguments to propagate to `ChiseStage`, you need to propagate them:

```scala
object DecoupledGcdDriver extends App {
    (new ChiselStage)emitVerilog(new DecoupledGcd(16), args)
}
```

You can see that `ChiselStage.emitVerilog` accepts `args` in the [Chisel API Docs](https://www.chisel-lang.org/api/latest/chisel3/stage/ChiselStage.html).

Answer (score 3):

Set the arguments as a call to the `ChiselStage`. Below is an example. This will put the Verilog and FIRRTL in the output dir. The output dir will be created if it doesn't exists.

```scala
object MyAsyncResetModuleGen extends App {  
  val myverilog = (new ChiselStage).emitVerilog(
    new MyAsyncResetModule,
     
    //args
    Array("--target-dir", "output/")
  )
}
```